# How to specify in ant script to place resource file like xml/properties files on classpath?

Tags: java, xml, ant, build

How can i specify in ant script to include some xmls and properties file on classpath ? Like jars can be specified in manifest attribute by declaring all the jars in "Class-Path" .. Is there anything similar to that for xml/properties file?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you looking for runnable jar? Add those resources into jar.

Comment: Add a directory path to the "Class-Path" entry of the manifest. Files can then be accessed relative to this path